# XPATH to elements

Tags: xml, xpath, xmldocument, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

I'm trying to get the list of tblActions from an xmlfile but keep getting nothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<SecurityDS xmlns="http://tempuri.org/SecurityDS.xsd">
  <tblActiveDirectoryConfig>
    <AuthenticationEnabled>0</AuthenticationEnabled>
    <SSOEnabled>0</SSOEnabled>
    <DefaultLoginDomain />
  </tblActiveDirectoryConfig>
  <tblAccountPolicy>
    <PolicyId>1</PolicyId>
    <PasswordHistoryPeriod>6</PasswordHistoryPeriod>
    <MinPassword>3</MinPassword>
    <MaxPassword>30</MaxPassword>
    <LoginAttemptsAllowed>3</LoginAttemptsAllowed>
    <PasswordExpiration>60</PasswordExpiration>
  </tblAccountPolicy>
  <tblAction>
    <ActionID>1</ActionID>
    <ActionName>Adjust(w/ value)</ActionName>
    <ActionSeqID>10</ActionSeqID>
    <CreateDate>2002-07-15T17:49:18.1470000-05:00</CreateDate>
    <ModifyDate>2002-07-15T17:49:18.1470000-05:00</ModifyDate>
  </tblAction>
  <tblAction>
    <ActionID>2</ActionID>
    <ActionName>State0(ex. Unoccupied for BV, BO)</ActionName>
    <ActionSeqID>20</ActionSeqID>
    <CreateDate>2002-07-15T17:53:03.4900000-05:00</CreateDate>
    <ModifyDate>2002-07-15T17:53:03.4900000-05:00</ModifyDate>
  </tblAction>
  <tblAction>
    <ActionID>3</ActionID>
    <ActionName>State1(ex. Occupied for BV, BO)</ActionName>
    <ActionSeqID>21</ActionSeqID>
    <CreateDate>2002-07-15T17:53:14.4470000-05:00</CreateDate>
    <ModifyDate>2002-07-15T17:53:14.4470000-05:00</ModifyDate>
  </tblAction>
</<SecurityDS>
```

My Xpath I've tried:

- .//tblAction
- //tblAction
- /SecurityDS/tblAction

My code snippet :

```
XmlNode root = fileContents.DocumentElement;

var nodes = root.SelectNodes(xpath_value);
```

In all cases I get zero nodes selected.

Comment: `//tblAction` Should work.  Maybe it's because your XML is malformed (you have an extra bracket < before the closing SecurityDS)  There is a free tool here called XPath Builder that may help you: http://www.bubasoft.net/

Comment: Your problem may be related to the default namespace used your XML file. Usually, this namespace has to be registered with the search functionality before using it. Just to make sure that it's not related to the namespace remove the `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/SecurityDS.xsd"` declaration and try again.

Comment: The question should include information about the code or tool you’re using the run the XPath query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML has *default namespace* -namespace declared without prefix- here :

```
<SecurityDS xmlns="http://tempuri.org/SecurityDS.xsd">
```

Descendant element inherits ancestor default implicitly, unless otherwise specified. To access element in namespace when using `XmlDocument` class, you need to map a prefix to the namespace URI, and then use that prefix properly in the XPath :

```cs
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
//register mapping of prefix to namespace uri 
nsmgr.AddNamespace("d", "http://tempuri.org/SecurityDS.xsd");
//pass the namespace manager instance as 2nd param of SelectNodes():
var nodes = root.SelectNodes(".//d:tblAction", nsmgr);
```

Comment: Ding ding. Winner winner. Chicken dinner. You sir are xml ninja. This worked an absolute charm. Thank you very much.